# PHP - Slashes are coming after using the stripshales for String

Tags: php, string, stripslashes

i am using mysqli connection.

```
 $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
```

Storing the Data in DB with below syntax

```
$site_description = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['site_description']);  
$conn->query("UPDATE `r_site_details` SET  `site_description` = '".$site_description."' WHERE `id` = ".$id);
input : Telangana's
```

it adding slashes.
But when i output the value with `stripslashes` its still showing the slashes in the string

```
$query = $conn->query("select * from r_site_details where id=$id")or die(mysqli_error());
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
    echo stripslashes($result["site_description"]) // output : Telangana\'s
```

Comment: There is a lot happening - and not shown here - between posting a form and echoing a variable from a database query. You should `var_dump()` the variable at the different stages to see where the problem is as that is impossible to tell from just these 2 lines.

Comment: okay let me Post my Complete Script, Thanks @jeroen

Comment: You should first check what values the variable has at what stage, perhaps it is already escaped when you get the POST value for example.

Comment: @jeroen, Hope you can see the complete scenario.

Comment: If you are unwilling to inspect the value of your variables, you will never be able to debug any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont Find a Optimize Solution, Just Tried to Replace the Slashes it works fine,

`echo str_replace('\"', '"',str_replace("\'", "'", $result["site_description`"]));

Can anyone suggest me an alternative Solution.

Answer (score -1):

Hope [Disabling Magic Quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) could help you.